# What is the 'defer' equivalent for Java

Tags: java, go, try-catch-finally

This is just a short example of Go code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("world") //use of keyword 'defer'

    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

I am finding an equivalent of 'defer' in Java.

Instead of 'defer' I can use

```
try {
    //do something
} finally {
    //code using defer
}
```

Is there any alternative without using try/catch/finally?

Comment: Are you looking to perform cleanup?

Comment: What's wrong with `finally`?

Comment: yeah clean-up like closing connection and to free memory..

Comment: There's no direct translation, and how you write go isn't how you write java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java 7 has a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.
>
> The following example reads the first line from a file. It uses an
>   instance of BufferedReader to read data from the file. BufferedReader
>   is a resource that must be closed after the program is finished with
>   it:
>
> ```
> static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
>     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
>         return br.readLine();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the resource declared in the try-with-resources
>   statement is a BufferedReader. The declaration statement appears
>   within parentheses immediately after the try keyword. The class
>   BufferedReader, in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface
>   java.lang.AutoCloseable. Because the BufferedReader instance is
>   declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed
>   regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly
>   (as a result of the method BufferedReader.readLine throwing an
>   IOException).

Answer (score 4):

In java 7 and above you can use try-with-resource:

```
public static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
     return br.readLine();
  }
}
```

when you exit the try it will close the resource
docs: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this with some extra libraries. Unfortunately, there is the `IOException` to deal with.

```
import com.google.common.io.Closer;
import lombok.Cleanup;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    @SneakyThrows(IOException.class)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @Cleanup Closer defer = Closer.create();
        defer.register(() -> System.out.println("world"));
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

If you don't like dealing with the exception, and if it's worth it for you, you could wrap it like this

```
import com.google.common.io.Closer;
import lombok.Cleanup;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @Cleanup Defer defer = Defer.create();
        defer.register(() -> System.out.println("world"));
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

// in some util package
class Defer implements Closeable {
    private final Closer closer;

    private Defer(Closer closer) {
        this.closer = closer;
    }

    public static Defer create() {
        return new Defer(Closer.create());
    }

    public <C extends Closeable> C register(C closeable) {
        return this.closer.register(closeable);
    }

    @SneakyThrows(IOException.class)
    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.closer.close();
    }
}
```